# retrieve only n elements for each category in a django queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to return n articles for each category. here is my models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
       ordering = ['-updated']
```

I think something like this will work but is it optimal ?!

```
articles = []
categories = Category.objects.all()
for c in categories:
     articles.append(Article.objects.filter(category=c)[:5])
```

is there another way to retrieve only the n last articles for each category ?

Comment: `articles.append(Article.objects.filter(category=c)[:5])` How? Your `Article` model doesn't have any field named `category`.

Comment: sorry. i updated my question